# SocketError with Mailboxer gem when not connected to the internet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, rubygems, mailboxer

I am using the mailboxer gem.  When not connected to the internet and using my localhost, if I try to send a message from one user of my site to another user of my site, I get the following error:

```
SocketError (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known):
```

What does this mean?  Is the gem somehow connected to mail boxer's servers?  I do not want to be dependent on someone else's servers for the internal messaging of my site, so I need to find out why mailboxer will not work if not connected to the internet?  If the gem is dependent on their servers, how do I know that they are not looking at the messages?

Comment: Mailboxer's github page says they have added support for emails and one needs to set that up in the initialization. Have a look here: https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app/blob/master/config/initializers/mailboxer.rb. I could be wrong.